# Custom metrics in keras to evaluate sign prediction

Tags: python, keras

I am working on a regression problem. One of performance metrics for this problem is "sign accuracy", which means I want to see whether the predict value has the same sign of the true value. I know `mse` could somehow show the closeness between the predict value and the true value, but I would like to see the sign accuracy during the validation.

To be more specific, after training, I use the way below to check the accuracy. What I want to custom the metrics is to realize the way below during validation.
`(np.multiply(predict_label,test_label)>0).sum()/float(predict_label.shape[0])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement it in a similar way to accuracy:

```
def sign_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.greater(y_true * y_pred, 0.), axis=-1)
```

To test it:

```
y_true = np.random.rand(5, 1) - 0.5
y_pred = np.random.rand(5, 1) - 0.5
acc = K.eval(sign_accuracy(K.variable(y_true), K.variable(y_pred)))

print(y_true)
[[ 0.20410185]
 [ 0.12085985]
 [ 0.39697642]
 [-0.28178138]
 [-0.37796012]]

print(y_pred)
[[-0.38281826]
 [ 0.14268927]
 [ 0.19218624]
 [ 0.21394845]
 [ 0.04044269]]

print(acc)
[ 0.  1.  1.  0.  0.]
```

The mean over axis 0 is taken automatically by Keras when you call `fit()` or `evaluate()`, so you don't need to sum `acc` and divide it by `y_pred.shape[0]`.

This metric can also be applied to multidimensional variables:

```
y_true = np.random.rand(5, 3) - 0.5
y_pred = np.random.rand(5, 3) - 0.5
acc = K.eval(sign_accuracy(K.variable(y_true), K.variable(y_pred)))

print(y_true)
[[ 0.02745352 -0.27927986 -0.47882833]
 [-0.40950793 -0.16218984  0.19184008]
 [ 0.25002487 -0.08455175 -0.03606459]
 [ 0.09315503 -0.19825522  0.19801222]
 [-0.32129431 -0.02256616  0.47799333]]

print(y_pred)
[[-0.06733171  0.18156806  0.28396574]
 [ 0.04054056 -0.45898607 -0.10661648]
 [-0.05162396 -0.34005141 -0.25910923]
 [-0.26283177  0.01532359  0.33764032]
 [ 0.2754057   0.26896232  0.23089488]]

print(acc)
[ 0.          0.33333334  0.66666669  0.33333334  0.33333334]
```

Comment: For the first case you give, can the desired output be `40%` or `0.4`? Do you mean if I put this `sign_accuracy` to the command `model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mae', metrics=[sign_accuracy])`, I will get `0.4`?

Comment: Yes. Keras takes average internally.