# Custom metrics in keras to evaluate directional accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am developing a metric in keras to evaluate if the direction of the model prediction is correct.  My model looks at forex historical data and predicts the close price of the next candle.  I have a callback class that does this calculation, but I really want to convert it into a loss function, my function is kind of a hack and does not use the keras tensors so it is not working as a loss function.

I have looked at [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46735166/custom-metrics-in-keras-to-evaluate-sign-prediction), but it is looking at the sign of `y_true` and `y_pred`.  My true and predictions are all positive so that method just goes to 1.0.  I need something that will look at `close` value of `y_true[n]`, `y_true[n-1]`, `y_pred[n]`, and `y_pred[n-1]`.  Then if the values at `n` is greater (or less than) than `n-1` for both `y_pred` and `y_true` then the direction is predicted correctly.  Then `1 - sum(correct_values)/total_values` would be my loss.

I am picturing something along the lines of

```py
def directional_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return 1 - (K.equal(K.sign(y_true - y_true[n-1]), K.sign(y_pred - y_pred[n-1)))/K.count(y_true)
```

I know there is not a `K.count` method, but you get the idea.

I am still learning about tensors, so any help you can provide on how to implement this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of **ChatGPT** I figured it out:

```py
def directional_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_diff = y_true[1:] - y_true[:-1]  # takes difference of n and n-1 for entire array
    y_pred_diff = y_pred[1:] - y_pred[:-1]
    y_true_directions = K.sign(y_true_diff)  # K.sign returns 1.0 for positive -1.0 for negative 
    y_pred_directions = K.sign(y_pred_diff)  # and 0 for no change

    match_count = K.sum(K.cast(K.equal(y_true_directions, y_pred_directions), dtype='float32'))
    # K.equal returns true if equal, False if not.  K.cast converts true to 1.0 and false to 0.0
    # K.sum totals the array i.e. counts the True values
    total_count = K.cast(K.shape(y_true_diff)[0], dtype='float32') # length of array in tensor

    return 1- (match_count / total_count)
```

I would be curious if this could be done with `Keras.backend.rnn`.  I looked into it but could not figure out how to set it up.  I would assume it would be a more efficient calculation.

Answer (score -1):

There is no `K.count` method in TensorFlow. upgrade Tensorflow and use `K.sum` and `K.cast`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

def directional_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    n = K.shape(y_true)[0]
    y_true_diff = y_true[n-1] - y_true[n-2]
    y_pred_diff = y_pred[n-1] - y_pred[n-2]
    cpredictions = K.sum(K.cast(K.equal(K.sign(y_true_diff), K.sign(y_pred_diff)), dtype=K.floatx()))
    totalValues = K.cast(n - 1, dtype=K.floatx())
    return 1 - (cpredictions / totalValues)
```

Comment: If I am understanding what is happening correctly then n is the length of the tensor, so `y_true[n-1]` and `y_true[n-2]` (same for `y_pred`) are then returning the last and second to last values.  Can this be changed so that it calculates the difference on the whole batch?  Or am I misunderstanding what the code is doing?